# How to get the last character and first character from a long string using `Util class`?

Tags: ios, string, malloc, substring

I use the below code to get  `the last character` , there comes a error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x....)
```

So I lldb it:

```
(lldb) po originStr.length
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7fff5f010f80.
(lldb) po [originStr substringFromIndex:originStr.length - 1]
error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7fff5f010f80.
```

And my originStr is very long:
Printing description of originStr:

```
(__NSCFString *) originStr = 0x00007f9e2d084c20 @"static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/2d2f44bea6384d66828db17a5a7e3490.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/50269cabce1f48658ec449bc66594dbb.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/12d034621c2d4c238271b0a1abfd97a1.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/b3d3367470c843df894f8d967a5c3584.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/735b392f0f7848ae878e2c20c8e61096.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/d7192235da2c46e88e62e9c54c6eb126.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/1c7fe1c7bd5a4f0984df7a311c7bfb64.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/1471802d68ac49c7ab62973b220d17a6.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/feefe467f9564a3ea775b945d54b4f4e.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/b4c36ecd16cb41c0a86187ee78835ebb.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/a230c5605e0a47e7a0f429471a5a19e8.jpg"
```

EDIT:My originStr is down from server, the `dic` is the data:

```
NSString *originStr = dic[@"image"];
```

This is originStr comes from.

EDIT:

I have get the reason, because I used the function to remove last and first special character in `Util` class.I have tested if I do the operation in the `class` which I generate the `long string`,it works fine, if in the `Util`, it will goes wrong.

The below is my `Util's` function:

```
@interface Util : NSObject

+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr lastCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter;

+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr firstCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter;
//
+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr firstAndLastCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter;

@end

#import "Util.h"

@implementation Util

+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr lastCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter {
    if (originStr.length == 0) {

        return originStr;
    }

    NSString *after_str;
    NSString *last_str = [originStr substringFromIndex:[originStr length] - 1];  
    // This line above code goes wrong. It shows:Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2,address=0x7fff5eabdff8),and I tried to po the originStr.length,it shows:
    //(lldb) po originStr.length
    //error: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0x7fff5eabdf80.

    if ([last_str isEqualToString:removeCharacter]) {

        after_str =[originStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, originStr.length -1)];

    }else {
        after_str = originStr;
    }
    return after_str;
}

+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr firstCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter {
    if (originStr.length == 0) {

        return originStr;
    }
    NSString *after_str;
    NSString *first_str = [originStr substringToIndex:1];
    if ([first_str isEqualToString:removeCharacter]) {


        after_str = [originStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, originStr.length -1)];
    }else {
        after_str = originStr;
    }

    return originStr;
}

+ (NSString *)removeString:(NSString *)originStr firstAndLastCharacterIfItIs:(NSString *)removeCharacter {

    NSString *str_last_removed = [Util removeString:originStr lastCharacterIfItIs:removeCharacter];
    return [Util removeString:str_last_removed firstAndLastCharacterIfItIs:removeCharacter];
}

@end
```

I think is the `Util` class has limited memory, so it cause the issue.

Comment: Apparently the problem is not in the substringFromIndex: method. Please show how the string is created. This can be either deallocated memory or out of memory issue.

Comment: I might agree with @StanislavPankevich, I tried creating an NSString, and NSLog substringFromIndex: longString.length - 1 and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: @Happiehappie I have edited my question, and I get the reason caused my issue, but I don't know what's the real answer to the issue.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich I have edited my question, it shows more information to the issue,that is caused by my`Util` class, but I don't know the real answer.

Comment: Do you have any information on which line causes that? Instead of wanting us to examine your entire class

Comment: @Happiehappie I am sorry,I have added comment lines in Util.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let trimmedString: String = (address as! NSString).substringFromIndex(max(address!.length-1,0));
```

This is for getting last character from a long string

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in playground and it worked fine

```
let longString = "static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/2d2f44bea6384d66828db17a5a7e3490.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/50269cabce1f48658ec449bc66594dbb.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/12d034621c2d4c238271b0a1abfd97a1.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/b3d3367470c843df894f8d967a5c3584.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/735b392f0f7848ae878e2c20c8e61096.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/d7192235da2c46e88e62e9c54c6eb126.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/1c7fe1c7bd5a4f0984df7a311c7bfb64.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/1471802d68ac49c7ab62973b220d17a6.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/feefe467f9564a3ea775b945d54b4f4e.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/b4c36ecd16cb41c0a86187ee78835ebb.jpg,static/res/upload/headImage/2016-7-18/a230c5605e0a47e7a0f429471a5a19e8.jpg"
let lastChar = longString.characters.last!
```

If you're only doing this in objective-c, try

```
NSString *lastChar = [state substringFromIndex: [longString length] - 1] //instead of dot notation
```